# JDBC variable names when called in the groovy script not giving the correct value for a CSV parameterization

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a JMeter test where a CSV file containing multiple rows of comma separated values example:- internalID,drivername, usreg,canadareg. I am basically using the CSV file to compare the values with the database table values. To compare the values to database values, I am adding a JDBC request with a query 'select internalID,drivername,usreg,canadareg from data where internalid ='${internalID'}' and providing the variables names to store the column data result. I use the groovy JSR233 and call the variables names in the script by declaring String a = vars.get("dintID_${counter}") where dintID is the variable name provided in the JDBC . The issue is when I run the script the first line of data in CSV files gets executed successfully, then the second line data in CSV file is passed to SQL statement correct, however the vars.get("dintid_${counter}") always stays at previous record meaning it does not go to next internalid(dintID). I have checked that my counter is incrementing. No idea how to resolve the issue. Does anyone know what mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) you will see that:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as **caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

So if the `counter` is a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) - it will always be the initial value and it won't increment on subsequent iterations.

So you need to change the line to:

```
String a = vars.get('dintID_' + vars.get('counter'))
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks so much!. While debugging the code found that the variable names declared in the JDBC request are not incrementing, however the 'Result variable name' which stores the array of the SQL result in the JDBC getting the records from the CSV. I want the 'Variable names' in the JDBC  request to increment to the next record supplied by the CSV file, any idea how we can do this.